# Simple Java Ant build problem

Tags: java, xml, ant, build

Completely new to Ant and I have just a simple problem.  I'm running ant with a input file: `ant -Dargs="input.txt" run` but it says it cannot find `input.txt` (No such file or directory).  I have the `build.xml` file and `input.txt` in the same directory, above `src` and `bin`.  Here is my `build.xml` file, am I missing something?

```
<project name="Project" default="compile" basedir=".">

  <description>
    A build file for a project
  </description>

  <!-- global properties for this build file -->
  <property name="source.dir" location="src"/>
  <property name="build.dir" location="bin"/>
  <property name="doc.dir" location="doc"/>
  <property name="main.class" value="proj.ProjMain"/>

  <!-- set up some directories used by this project -->
  <target name="init" description="setup project directories">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${doc.dir}"/>
  </target>

  <!-- Compile the java code in ${src.dir} into ${build.dir} -->
  <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile java sources">
    <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}"/>
  </target>

  <!-- execute the program with the fully qualified name in ${build.dir} -->
  <target name="run" description="run the project">
    <java dir="${build.dir}" classname="${main.class}" fork="yes">
        <arg line="${args}"/>
    </java>
  </target>

  <!-- Delete the build & doc directories and Emacs backup (*~) files -->
  <target name="clean" description="tidy up the workspace">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${doc.dir}"/>
    <delete>
      <fileset defaultexcludes="no" dir="${source.dir}" includes="**/*~"/>
    </delete>
  </target>

  <!-- Generate javadocs for current project into ${doc.dir} -->
  <target name="doc" depends="init" description="generate documentation">
    <javadoc sourcepath="${source.dir}" destdir="${doc.dir}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: which directory input.txt is in ?

Answer (score 6):

The command `ant -Dargs="input.txt" run` will run the following target:

```
  <!-- execute the program with the fully qualified name in ${build.dir} -->
  <target name="run" description="run the project">
    <java dir="${build.dir}" classname="${main.class}" fork="yes">
        <arg line="${args}"/>
    </java>
  </target>
```

As written in the comment, this target executes a Java program **from** the `${build.dir}` directory (which is here `bin`), passing the command line arguments to it. So, if `input.txt` is above `bin`, you should run:

```
$ ant -Dargs="../input.txt" run
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`basedir`** parameter in the **project** tag indicates the directory from which the build file's reference are taken when the absolute path is not specified. So your **`input.txt`** should be ***relative*** to your **`basedir`** or you should mention the absolute path to your **`input.txt`**.

In your case, the basedir refers to the directory where your build file resides. So, if the input.txt is in the same directory as your build file is, it should work fine

Comment: It's `proj.ProjMain` that is complaining, not ant.